# Run a macro reading sheet names from an XLS file

Tags: excel, vba, command, exec, xls

I'd like to run a macro that's reading all sheet names from an XLS file, and then being able to run the macro from the Run Command.
How is it possible?
For the moment I have the following code but I'd like to generalise it to other files (basically inputting the filename as a parameter in this macro and command).

```
Sub FnGetSheetsName()
    Dim mainworkBook As Workbook
    Set mainworkBook = ActiveWorkbook
    For i = 1 To mainworkBook.Sheets.Count
        'Either we can put all names in an array , here we are printing all the names in Sheet 2
        mainworkBook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & i) = mainworkBook.Sheets(i).Name
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a macro enabled workbook.
2. Use one of the cell in Sheet1 to specify the path to excel file whose sheet names you want.
3. In Sheet1, insert an Active X Control button using developer mode.
4. In the code behind of the button (double click on the button keeping design mode enabled in developer tab -> VBA window opens), add following VB code and save it:

   ```
   Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

   Dim sheetCount As Integer
   Dim mainWorkBook, workbook1 As Workbook

   Set mainWorkBook = ActiveWorkbook
   Set workbook1 = Workbooks.Open(Range("A2"))

   'Clear the contents of sheet 2, starting from row 2 - verify the last cell in sheet
   Selection = mainWorkBook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A2:ZZ104857").ClearContents

   If mainWorkBook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2") = "" Then
       MsgBox ("Enter Excel path")
       GoTo exit1
   End If

   For sheetCount = 1 To workbook1.Sheets.Count
       'Put sheet names of excel file in sheet 2 of macro book - you can find sheet names in Sheet2 starting from A2 cell.
       mainWorkBook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & sheetCount + 1).Value = workbook1.Sheets(sheetCount).Name
   Next sheetCount

   exit1:
   workbook1.Close (False)

   End Sub
   ```
5. In the Sheet1 (of macro workbook), enter the excel path (whose sheetnames you want) in cell A2.
6. Click the Active X button (keeping design mode disabled).
7. You can find the result in Sheet2 of the macro workbook (Add suitable column names in first row of Sheet1 and Sheet2 of macro workbook for readability, if needed).

[image: screenshot sheet1]